# WCF Service data limits with SSL

Tags: silverlight, wcf, ssl, maxreceivedmessagesize

I've managed to set up my Web Service to use SSL but now some calls that initially worked are now failing because the MaxReceivedMessageSize is too small.

The service returns data from a database using linq and the amount of elements retrieved is limited using

```
.take(400);
```

this works fine when I'm not using SSL but using SSL causes the call to fail, does SSL increase the message size?

Is it generally a good idea to increase the MaxReceivedMessageSize for this case or should I attempt to get the data in chunks, if so does anyone have any suggestions on how I could go about doing this, I'm using Silverlight with ASync calls.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that SSL would increase the actual amount of traffic due to the additional encryption.

Either of your suggestions would work, however, I personally would increase the 
`MaxReceivedMessageSize`, ensuring that `maxBufferSize` is also adjusted

Comment: Just to test I set the MaxReceivedMessageSize to equal int.MaxValue this fixed the issue but i've read that setting the size high can cause security issues.

Comment: I am not sure how setting the amount of data that can be sent could either increase or decrease security when used with SSL.

Comment: I read that it can increase the effectiveness of DDOS attacks against the system, not sure if its true though.

Comment: Unlikely, the concept of DDOS is to send too much data 'TO' your webserver so that is unable to process requests accordingly, typically flooding the resources. I would also assume that a user needs to have been authenticated in some manner before being able to access this request anyway.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me :), I'll stick to increasing the MaxReceivedMessageSize and MaxBufferSize. Thanks again